# What is the domain of $x^x$ when $ x<0$

Tags: calculus, analysis

I know that $x^x$ for all $x>0$

but what is negative values for that function which give a real number

for example  $$f(-1)=(-1)^{-1}=-1\in R$$

I try to put sequence for that but i faild

is there any help

thanks for all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x^x$ is well defined as a real function for $$(0,\infty) \cup \{ -\frac{m}{2n+1}| m, n \in {\mathbb N} \}$$

Comment: Make sure that $2n+1$ should be a prime number or that $\frac{m}{2n+1}$ is reduced.

Comment: @Arbuja Why? If it is not reduced, after reducing it the denominator is still odd...

Comment: Your right, Never mind....

Answer (score 2):

Set $y = -x$.

Thus, we have:

$x^x = (-y)^{-y}$ when $y \ge 0$

Or equivalently,

$$x^x = \frac{1}{(-y)^{y}}$$

Which can be simplified to:

$$x^x = \frac{1}{(-1)^{y} y^y}$$

Therefore, the domain of $x^x$ consists of both reals and complex numbers depending on the value of $(-1)^y$ or to be more precise depending on the value of $y$.

Answer (score 1):

For negative values of $x$, when $x$ is not an integer, you run into surly problems involving complex numbers.  These entail a study of the complex log function and its branches.

Clearly, $x\mapsto x^x$ makes sense for positive $x$.  It also makes sense for negative integer values of $x$.  It is not defined at $0$.

Comment: but when x is not negative integer like x=-e
its give complex value

Comment: Yes, because of a choice of a branch of the log.  $(-e)^{-e} = (e^{1 + (2n + 1)i\pi})^{-e}.$  Now you must pick an $n$, for an infinity of values is possible from this expression.

Comment: @ncmathsadist $e^{\ln{x}}\neq{x}$ when $x<0$. Take $x=-1$, for example.